# Get numbers matching a pattern from the output of ls?

Tags: linux, bash, ls, filenames, text-formatting

I have a folder, and when I execute `ls` in it, it outputs

```
t-1-myFirstTest.c
myFile.c
t-42-my_second_test.c
t-3-test1234.c
  .
  .
  .
mySecondFile.c
t-21-tset241.c
```

I want to delete everything of this text except the newlines and the numbers between `t-` and the second `-`. So the output of this previous one should be

```
1
42
3
 .
 .
 .
21
```

I have a solution, but I think it is really bad. If the folder we are talking about is actually in the current directory, then I used

```
ls | grep -o -E t-[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9_]+.c | grep -o -E t-[0-9]+ | grep -o -E [0-9]+
```

Any better way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing the output of `ls` is a bad idea (the output of `ls` is strictly for looking at). For more info on that, see the question "[Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)".

This is how you may do it under `/bin/sh`:

```
for filename in t-*-*.c; do
    [ ! -f "$filename" ] && continue
    number=${filename#t-}   # remove "t-" from start of filename
    number=${number%%-*}    # remove everything from first "-" in what remains
    printf '%s\n' "$number"
done
```

This would iterate over all filenames in the current directory whose name matches the pattern `t-*-*.c`.  For each of these names, the `t-` bit is stripped off from the start, and then the second `-` and everything afterwards is removed with another parameter expansion.

The expansion `${variable#word}` would remove the (shortest) match for `word` from the *start* of `$variable`, while `${variable%%word}` would remove the (longest) match for `word` from the *end* of the string.

With `bash`, using regular expression matching on the filenames:

```
for filename in t-*-*.c; do
    [ ! -f "$filename" ] && continue
    if [[ "$filename" =~ ^t-([0-9]+)- ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done
```

This would match and capture the digits after `t-` in each filename. The captured group of digits is available in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` after a successful match.  The index `1` refers to the first capture group (parenthesis) in the regular expression.

For a slow, but possibly comfortable (as in "familiar") solution, you may want to call an external command to parse out the bit of the string that you're interested in:

```
for filename in t-*-*.c; do
    [ ! -f "$filename" ] && continue
    cut -d '-' -f 2 <<<"$filename"
done
```

This assumes `bash` and that you're ok with calling `cut` in a loop. This would be much slower than using operation built into the shell itself.  The `cut` command here is asked to return the second `-`-delimited field from the string passed to it from `bash` (using a "here-string" redirection).

Answer (score 3):

According to your output:

`ls|awk -F"-" '{print $2}'`

Should work, but if you want to take into account the `t-` part then

`ls|grep ^t-|awk -F"-" '{print $2}'`

or

`ls|awk -F"t-" '{print $2}'|awk -F"-" '{print $1}'`

Comment: I would add a condition to this to make it a bit better - no blank lines for files that don't match: `ls | awk -F- 'NF == 3 { print $2 }'. 'NF >= 3' might also be appropriate, but the question isn't real clear on that...

Answer (score 3):

When I created the list of files from your example, my `ls` sorts them this way:

```
$ ls -1
myFile.c
mySecondFile.c
t-1-myFirstTest.c
t-21-tset241.c
t-3-test1234.c
t-42-my_second_test.c
```

As a result, the bash function below outputs the newlines and numbers for the files in the same order.

> I want to delete everything of this text except the newlines and the numbers between t- and the second -

I interpreted this to mean that filenames that do not match `t-` should be "deleted except for the newline", meaning: output a blank line for those filenames, but otherwise output the numbers between the dashes.

```
lsnums ()
{
    for f in *
    do
        if [[ "$f" =~ t-([[:digit:]]+)- ]]; then
            printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        else
            echo
        fi
    done
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
$ lsnums


1
21
3
42
```

... where the two blank lines correspond to the first type files beginning with `my` instead of `t-`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply done with :

```
ls | cut -d '-' -f 2
```